# Class-D audio amplifier produces a sawtooth wave on the output, not sine

Tags: low-pass, sine, class-d, sawtooth-waveform

I am using a [MAX9744](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/MAX9744.pdf) Class-D amplifier and want to get a sine wave in the output. Someone suggests using an LC low-pass filter for this, and in the datasheet of the amplifier, the values for inductors and capacitors are provided. When I constructed the circuit (I attached the schematics), the output was a high-frequency triangular wave, not a sinusoid. The input is 100-1000 Hz sine wave.

Why is this happening? Is it not enough to build an LC filter circuit in the output of the class-D amplifier to get a sine output?

What else do I need to add/change to get a sine wave?

The circuit from the datasheet, I used the values of L and C for 4 Ω load. The inductors that I use are the color ring inductors 0307 1/4 W of 0.47 uH, the image is attached.

[image]

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: well, "someone suggested" is not really strong enough of a term: the whole functional principle of a class-D amplifier is that something at the output gets rid of the high-frequency switching.

Comment: Can you confirm that you built the LC-RLC filter as depicted in Figure 8 and described in table 8, and not just an LC filter? No matter what you did: how did you load the filter, and how did you measure, i.e. at which point of your load did you attach your oscilloscope(?) or other measurement device?

Comment: Yes, the circuit is exactly as in the datasheet. I attach the oscilloscope probes at the two ends of a speaker, after the filter, as depicted in the Figure 8.

Comment: Does the speaker make any audible noise during measurement? What happens to the triangle, if you reduce the input amplitude?

Comment: Yes, it works. When I change the input frequency, the speaker's frequency is also changing accordingly

Comment: How exactly did you connect the scope? You said 'probes', did you use two probes on on each side of the speaker, or did you connect one probe with the probe tip to one side of the speaker and probe ground to the other side? Is/are your probe/s compensated properly?

Comment: When I increase the amplitude of the input signal, the triangular wave oscillates very frequently, as if it is noise.

Comment: One probe of oscilloscope is connected to + side of the speaker, the other probe is connected to - side of the speaker.

Comment: Inductor saturation?

Comment: @BroBro  I specifically asked you to *reduce* the amplitude, not *increase* it, because, just as tobalt, I'd guess you're just overdriving the input.

Comment: When I reduce the amplitude, the wave does not changing significantly, just more stable in terms of oscillations

Comment: In general, does this circuit provide a sine output?

Comment: It should, if your input is a sine and of appropriate level.  Is your speaker really 4 Ohms?

Comment: What is the amplitude of the high frequency?

Comment: Show us pics or give us specific part numbers for the inductors you used for L1 & L2.

Comment: What frequency is your sawtooth problem? Is it your low frequency audio signal or is it the class-D 300lHz or 360kHz switching frequency that the filter removes? You mentioned oscillation then did you build it on a breadboard?

Comment: I added the information that you asked for. The sawtooth has a frequency of ~300kHz, I do not know what it can mean. The circuit is built on the breadbaoard. The speaker is 5 Ohm.

Comment: _"just more stable in terms of oscillations"_ This is why oscillograms was invented. It can mean so many things to so many people. Please capture this on your oscilloscope. Feel free to zoom out on the time scale if needed.

Comment: _"The inductors that I use are the color ring inductors 0307 1/4Wt of 0.47uF, the image is attached." Several issues here. I assume the uF is just a typo of uH. What's the saturation current on that inductor? I would suspect 100 less than you need, if not 1000. What's "1/4 Wt"?

Comment: Those inductors are wildly unsuitable for diving a 4-ohm speaker load.

Answer (score 5):

You are looking at the switching ripple at 300 **k**Hz. This is inaudible, albeit not nice.

Due to the scope's persistence, you can also see that this triangular waveform has a few 100 mV vertical "shift" on different captures. This is due to the instantaneous sine wave component.

Zoom out to a 5 ms time division and you should see the sine wave.

It is possible to suppress the ripple much more with a second LC filter if desired.

Comment: yes, this is what class D amps do by default.

Comment: unfortunately, I played around with zooming in and out, the wave is still triangular.

Comment: @BroBro I agree with tobalt. What you are seeing is 300kHz 40mV pk-pk, which is certainly class-D ripple, and not the low frequency analogue wave. Show us a 5ms/div & 1V/div scope trace.

Answer (score 0):

The normal for class-D 300kHz is already reduced to a very low level so what is the problem? I think the filter will work better if the circuit is built compactly on a pcb and if the inductors are larger. My very low power solar garden lights use a small inductor like that.